# Why does the translator's introduction to "The Complete Kobzar" claim that Ukraine has the sixth-highest per capita consumption of alcohol?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, the-complete-kobzar, peter-fedynsky, taras-shevchenko

The translator's introduction to *The Complete Kobzar* briefly describes some social problems in Ukraine; among other things, the translator claims that:

> According to the World Health Organization, Ukraine has the sixth highest per-capita adult alcohol consumption rate in the world and the highest among adolescents.

However, when I check WHO statistics, such as [here](https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/alcohol-recorded-per-capita-(15-)-consumption-(in-litres-of-pure-alcohol)), it was actually ranked 77th in 2019, a mere 6 years after the book was published. Several other lists that I've consulted have also failed to place Ukraine even in the top 10.

Can someone explain the discrepancy?